# Java skiplist implementation optimization

Tags: java, optimization, skip-lists

Im strugling with skiplist implementation in java. Basically everything works fine but `put` method takes too long to perform. Here's my code, I've been through tutorials and viewed some people's codes and I don't seem to see where's the problem(If You measure putting 100000 random elements it takes ages to work).

```
public class SkipList<K,V> {

    private final SkipListItem<K,V> head;
    private int currentLevel = 0;
    private static final Random random = new Random();
    private int height = 0;

    public SkipList() {
        this.head = new SkipListItem<>(null, null);
    }

    public V put(K key, V value) {
        return this.put(key, value, null, 0);
    }

    private V put(K key, V value, SkipListItem<K,V> previous, int level) {
        if(level > this.height) {
            for(int i=0,s=level-this.height ; i<s ; ++i) {
                this.addHeadItem();
            }
        }
        SkipListItem<K,V> addedItem = new SkipListItem<>(key, value);
        SkipListItem<K,V> insertAfter = this.findLowerItem(key, level);
        addedItem.setPrevious(insertAfter);
        if(insertAfter.getNext() != null) {
            insertAfter.getNext().setPrevious(addedItem);
            addedItem.setNext(insertAfter.getNext());
        }
        insertAfter.setNext(addedItem);
        if(previous != null) {
            addedItem.setBelow(previous);
            previous.setAbove(addedItem);
        }

        return (SkipList.random.nextBoolean()) ? this.put(key, value, addedItem, level+1) : value ;
    }

    private void addHeadItem() {
        SkipListItem<K,V> item = this.head;
        while(item.getAbove() != null) {
            item = item.getAbove();
        }
        SkipListItem<K,V> newHead = new SkipListItem<>(null,null);
        item.setAbove(newHead);
        newHead.setBelow(item);
        ++this.height;
    }

    private SkipListItem<K,V> findLowerItem(K key) {
        return this.findLowerItem(key,0);
    }

    private SkipListItem<K,V> findLowerItem(K key, int level) {
        SkipListItem<K,V> currentItem = this.head;
        for(int i=0 ; i<level ; ++i) {
            currentItem = currentItem.getAbove();
        }
        while(  currentItem.getNext() != null &&
                currentItem.getNext().getKey() != null &&
                currentItem.getNext().compareTo(key) < 0) {
            currentItem = currentItem.getNext();
        }
        return currentItem;
    }
    //...some other functions...
}
```

any ideas why is it taking so long?

Comment: Do some method profiling. What takes so long? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267594/java-profiling-how-can-i-get-a-method-by-method-analysis-of-my-application or some manual `System.nanoTime()` aggregation)

Comment: Can you include the code for `SkipListItem`?

Comment: Did you try step-by-step debug to insure that `put()` behaves as intended (i. e. searches using index, not 0-level list, and builds index correctly)?

Comment: Anyway, looking deeper it seems that you don't use index at all on `put()` operations -- when `level = 0`, upper levels aren't involved. To make it work, `findLowerItem()` should first search on top level (level = height), then lower and lower until given level is reached.

Answer (score 1):

At the first sight, whenever you insert new item, you go potentially through the whole list to find the position. This leads to linear complexity, so at the end inserting `n` items require `n*n` operations.

Specifically in your case the final number is 10 billions operations already quite complex so I could imagine this will take minutes to populate.